# I can't install the mc from the local repository

Tags: repository, oracle-linux

I created a machine with my own repository for the mc package. I connected the repository on the second machine and during the installation of the mc package I get this error:

```
No available modular metadata for modular package 'perl-IO-Socket-SSL-2.066-4.module+el8.6.0+20623+f0897f98.noarch', it cannot be installed on the system
No available modular metadata for modular package 'perl-Net-SSLeay-1.88-2.module+el8.6.0+20623+f0897f98.x86_64', it cannot be installed on the system
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'yum clean packages'.
Error: No available modular metadata for modular package
```

There is only one repository connected. The official repository is not connected.
I can't figure out how to solve this problem. Can you help?
In short, I downloaded the mc package along with all its dependencies with the repotrack command:

```
repotrack mc-4.8.19-9.el8.x86_64
```

Next, I created a repository using createrepo. Both machines are running Oracle Linux 8.
If I connect the official repository, then there is no such error and the mc package is installed successfully.

Comment: Did you try to google the error message? The [explanation and solution](https://forums.rockylinux.org/t/no-available-modular-metadata-package/6235/3) was on the second position for me, after Red Hat's paywall.